# Fetch from multiple, separate, collections with Express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database

I have a site where i need some data from my Mongo data to be shown. My problem, however, is that i need data from two collections. Collections that are completely separate and have nothing to do with each other.

Right now i have this in my routes for my profile-page:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res,next) {
   var resultArray = [];

   mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      var cursor = db.collection('users').find();
      cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
         resultArray.push(doc);
      }, function() {
         db.close();
         res.render('profile/index', {users: resultArray});
      });
   });
});
```

And this, of course, works perfectly fine. But how do i get a second `db.collection('colors').find();` to be passed along to my template too?

I'm sure it's something trivial, and me just not quite having the full grasp of things, but yeah.. I'm stuck..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [**async**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library which is best suited for this scenario. Where you need to run multiple tasks that do not depend on each other and when they all finish do something else, you should use **[`async.parallel()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)** method. The signature is `async.parallel(tasks, callback)`, where tasks is an array of functions.

It will immediately run all the functions in parallel, wait for all of them to call their task callback, and finally when all tasks are complete it will run callback (the final callback).

The following example demonstrates how this could be adapted for your use case:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        var locals = {};
        var tasks = [
            // Load users
            function(callback) {
                db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, users) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    locals.users = users;
                    callback();
                });
            },
            // Load colors
            function(callback) {
                db.collection('colors').find({}).toArray(function(err, colors) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    locals.colors = colors;
                    callback();
                });
            }
        ];

        async.parallel(tasks, function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
            if (err) return next(err); //If an error occurred, let express handle it by calling the `next` function
            // Here `locals` will be an object with `users` and `colors` keys
            // Example: `locals = {users: [...], colors: [...]}`
            db.close();
            res.render('profile/index', locals);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's very interesting, and definitely seems like a more proper way. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: It is the correct way because it handles asynchronous methods much better. In the other answer, you are bound to get incorrect results as the `resultsArray` is populated synchronously. A much better approach would be to use [**Promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as they offer a lot more flexibility when handling asynchronous tasks, and I would recommend anyone to consider using them before resorting to different solutions.

Comment: The general concept with promises is that they are containers for future values. When a promise receives the value (it is resolved) or when it is cancelled (rejected), it notifies all of its "listeners" who want to access this value.

Comment: You are THE MAN! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res,next) {
   var resultArray = {
                      users : [],
                      colors : []
                     };

   mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      var cursor = db.collection('users').find();
      cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
         resultArray.users.push(doc);
      }
      var colors = db.collection('colors').find();
      colors.forEach(function(doc,err){
          resultArray.colors.push(doc);
       }, function() {
         db.close();
         res.render('profile/index', {users: resultArray.users, colors: resultArray.colors});
      });
   });
});
```

Didn't have time to check it, but I'm pretty sure that it would work.